# Extract p-value from Kruskal-Wallis output

Tags: r, data-extraction, kruskal-wallis

Let's say I have a dataframe

```
> col1<-c(1,5,2,6,8,1,3,8,9,1,8)
> col2<-c(1,2,1,1,2,2,1,2,2,1,1)
> df<-data.frame(col1,col2)
> df

   col1 col2
1     1    1
2     5    2
3     2    1
4     6    1
5     8    2
6     1    2
7     3    1
8     8    2
9     9    2
10    1    1
11    8    1
```

I have ran the Kruskal-Wallis test with the data I have in `df`

```
> dfKW<-kruskal.test(col1~col2, data=df)
> dfKW

Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test

data:  col1 by col2
Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 1.695, df = 1, p-value = 0.1929
```

What I wish to do is to extract the p-value into a vector (only the value without the label 'p-value'). I have tried this:

```
> dfKWx<-sapply(dfKW, '[', 'p.value')
> dfKWx

statistic.NA parameter.NA      p.value       method    data.name 
          NA           NA           NA           NA           NA
```

With no luck, obviously.

The initial aid that I got from professor Google led me to the point I have described above.

All help is sincerely appreciated. Thank you!

PS. Please note that the data is only there to provide an example. I have not tested for the normal distribution nor do I wish to do so with these data. My original working data does not distribute normally, but I will not use it -or parts of it- as an example due to factors of confidentiality. The example data behaves similarly to my original working data.

Comment: `names(dfKW)` and `str(dfKW)` are useful to see what objects can be extracted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will give you the p value as a `numeric`:

```
> dfKW$p.value
[1] 0.1929473
```

Look at the "Value" section in `?kruskal.test`.

Comment: Thank you! I have a notorious tendency to skim through manuals. Now I wish that I would have given that one more time.